# Python Tkinter text syntax highlighting doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using `Brian Oakley's` `CustomText` class which features `syntax highlighting`. Unfortunately the `highlighting` doesn't seem to work when I configure the tags and create a highlighting pattern. Below is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class CustomText(tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


    def highlight_pattern(self, pattern, tag, start="1.0", end="end",
                          regexp=False):
        '''Apply the given tag to all text that matches the given pattern

        If 'regexp' is set to True, pattern will be treated as a regular
        expression.
        '''

        start = self.index(start)
        end = self.index(end)
        self.mark_set("matchStart", start)
        self.mark_set("matchEnd", start)
        self.mark_set("searchLimit", end)

        count = tk.IntVar()
        while True:
            index = self.search(pattern, "matchEnd","searchLimit",
                                count=count, regexp=regexp)
            if index == "": break
            self.mark_set("matchStart", index)
            self.mark_set("matchEnd", "%s+%sc" % (index, count.get()))
            self.tag_add(tag, "matchStart", "matchEnd")

class Arshi(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.createtext()

    def createtext(self):
        self.text = CustomText(self, bd=0, font=("Courier", 9))
        self.text.tag_configure("declaration", foreground="#376899")
        self.text.highlight_pattern("asdf", "declaration")
        self.text.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Arshi")
    window = Arshi(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the `highlight_pattern` function after inserting text. It doesn't happen automatically.